# Oracle Stored Procedure and Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to write a stored procedure to transform this:

```
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    ID    |   ESD    |  TD      |   IS_DB  | TEST_SET |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    1     |  10      |  20      |    1     |    2     |
|    2     |  30      |  (null)  |    1     |    2     |
|    3     |  40      |  (null)  |    1     |    2     |
|    4     |  50      |  60      |    0     |    2     |
|    5     |  (null)  |  70      |    1     |    2     |
|    6     |  75      |  100     |    1     |    2     |
|    7     |  (null)  |  80      |    1     |    2     |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

to this:

```
|----------|----------|
|  DT      |  FLAG    |
|----------|----------|
|  10      |  E       |
|  20      |  H       |
|  30      |  E       |
|  40      |  E       |
|  50      |  E       |
|  60      |  S       |
|  70      |  H       |
|  75      |  E       |
|  80      |  H       |
|  100     |  H       |
|----------|----------|
```

The business rules being:

For each row in the `TEST_DATA_SOVLP`:

1. If the current `ESD` value is not `null` then:

   - insert a row in TEMP with the values: `<ESD value>`, `E`
2. If the current `TD` value is not `null` then:

   - If `IS_DB=0` => insert in TEMP the values: `<TD value>`, `S`
   - If `IS_DB=1` => insert in TEMP the values: `<TD value>`, `H`

but I'm not getting anything close to what I'm expecting:

- Nothing get written in the TEMP table.
- The console display values that make no sense to me:

  20 H
  10 E
  20 H
  10 E
  20 H
  ...

**Questions** :

1. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my proc ?
2. Why no data are stored in TEMP ?
3. What could be a cleaner way to solve this problem ? 
   I tried using a SQL query (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429308/merging-2-columns-in-one)) without success.
   Note: I have multiple similar proc to write that I would like then to call from a 'master' proc that will summarize the logic.

Thank you

**1. Table storing some data**

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_DATA_SOVLP" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER,
   "ESD" NUMBER, 
    "TD" NUMBER, 
    "IS_DB" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0, 
    "TEST_SET" NUMBER
   )
```

**Some data**

```
INSERT INTO "TEST_DATA_SOVLP" (ID, ESD, TD, IS_DB, TEST_SET) VALUES ('1', '10', '20', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO "TEST_DATA_SOVLP" (ID, ESD, IS_DB, TEST_SET) VALUES ('2', '30', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO "TEST_DATA_SOVLP" (ID, ESD, IS_DB, TEST_SET) VALUES ('3', '40', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO "TEST_DATA_SOVLP" (ID, ESD, TD, IS_DB, TEST_SET) VALUES ('4', '50', '60', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO "TEST_DATA_SOVLP" (ID, TD, IS_DB, TEST_SET) VALUES ('5', '70', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO "TEST_DATA_SOVLP" (ID, ESD, TD, IS_DB,TEST_SET) VALUES ('6', '75', '100', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO "TEST_DATA_SOVLP" (ID, TD, IS_DB, TEST_SET) VALUES ('7', '80', '1', '2');
```

**2. Table to store results**

```
  CREATE TABLE "TEMP" 
   (    "DT" NUMBER, 
    "FLAG" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
   )
```

**3. PL/SQL manipulating the data and storing the results**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE S_OVLP 

AS 

   CURSOR cSH IS
      SELECT ID, ESD, TD, IS_DB, TEST_SET
      FROM TEST_DATA_SOVLP
      WHERE TEST_SET = 2;

    rec_csh cSH%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

 -- DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT('TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP');

  OPEN cSH;    

    LOOP

        FETCH cSH INTO rec_csh;
        EXIT WHEN cSH%NOTFOUND;

        IF rec_csh.esd IS NOT NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES (rec_csh.esd, 'E');
            dbms_output.put_line(rec_csh.esd || ' E');
        END IF;

        IF rec_csh.td IS NOT NULL THEN 
            IF rec_csh.is_db = 1 THEN     
                INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES (rec_csh.td, 'H');
                dbms_output.put_line(rec_csh.td || ' H');
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES (rec_csh.td, 'S');
                dbms_output.put_line(rec_csh.td || ' S');
            END IF;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

  CLOSE cSH;

END S_OVLP;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run this `INSERT INTO` , there is no need of procedure.

```
INSERT INTO temp 
SELECT esd, 
       'E' 
FROM   test_data_sovlp 
WHERE  esd IS NOT NULL 
  UNION ALL 
SELECT td, 
       CASE is_db 
         WHEN 0 THEN 'S' 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'H' 
       END AS FLAG 
FROM   test_data_sovlp 
WHERE  td IS NOT NULL
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1415f/2)

Comment: That's look good. Up voted the answer. Thanks. Is there a way to store the sequence of flags (ordered by TD) in a variable instead of a table. Aka  here `EEEESEHH`?

Comment: @HeyStackExchange : I don't fully understand what you are asking. It does not appear to do anything with this particular question. If you find this answer helpful, please mark this as answered and ask a separate question giving the details. Thanks!

Comment: Ya ok, there are always such comments. Marked it correct despite it doesn't explain the proc issues. Thanks

Comment: Raised a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433925/how-to-store-sql-result-in-a-variable-and-parse-the-result-to-identify-a-possibl to use this result.

Comment: @HeyStackExchange : Will be away for a while. Let others check. I'll see u later.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 1):

From your business rules, it seems you can do it just with two inserts, like these:

```
insert into temp
select esd, 'E' from TEST_DATA_SOVLP where test_set=2 and esd is not null;

insert into temp
select td, decode(is_db, 1, 'H', 'S') from TEST_DATA_SOVLP 
     where test_set=2 and td is not null;
```

Besides the conditions on `esd` and `td`, the selects also “embed” the condition on `test_set`, given by the cursor in your procedure.

The `decode` compares `is_db` with 1 and if matches, use `'H'`, otherwise uses `'S'` (so 2 would give the same result as 0; but then I suppose you need to check your data, since you have defined what to give only for 1 or 0).

### About the procedure

I've tested it on https://livesql.oracle.com and the output looks fine:

```
10 E
20 H
30 E
40 E
50 E
60 H
70 H
75 E
100 H
80 H
```

(The table has all `is_db = 1`, see the inserts you gave in the question).

Also, the `temp` table is populated accordingly. So, the problem can't be replicated and your original procedure seems to work fine as expected.

Comment: Thanks. You are right about the flag value for ESD, I will mark flag null for such condition. Much appreciated. Up voted.

Comment: Also note that in the insert statement you gave for testing, the line "50 60" has `is_db = 1` but in the table you have `0` and considered that to fill temp (it can confound when comparing results to check if everything's ok)

Comment: You are right. In fact IS_DB only apply to TD. It is not related to any value ESD can have. So the line 50 60, IS_DB=0 apply to TD.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got it right with the code below, changing the nested IF statement.
But I'm really disappointed with the way PL/SQL work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE S_OVLP 

AS 

   CURSOR cSH IS
      SELECT ID, ESD, TD, IS_DB, TEST_SET
      FROM TEST_DATA_SOVLP
      WHERE TEST_SET = 2;

    rec_csh cSH%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

  DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT('TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP');

  OPEN cSH;    

    LOOP

        FETCH cSH INTO rec_csh;
        EXIT WHEN cSH%NOTFOUND;

        IF rec_csh.esd IS NOT NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES (rec_csh.esd, 'E');
            dbms_output.put_line(rec_csh.esd || ' E');
        END IF;

        IF rec_csh.td IS NULL THEN 
            CONTINUE;
        END IF;

        IF rec_csh.is_db = 1 THEN     
            INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES (rec_csh.td, 'H');
            dbms_output.put_line(rec_csh.td || ' H');
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES (rec_csh.td, 'S');
            dbms_output.put_line(rec_csh.td || ' S');
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

  CLOSE cSH;

END S_OVLP;
```

Comment: It should be exactly the same. Which version of Oracle? Could it be you missed a commit and you've seen nothing because of this?

Comment: Too many `if` conditions and loops. Don't use this code. Edit your question and explain the required conditions to use to get the records for `temp` table. Never add images for sample data, use only plain text. A single `insert into select *` query can be written to do this, which will be much efficient than loops and conditions. Lastly, don't blame PL/SQL for the bad way you wrote the code. It seems you are yet to use the language's most powerful features.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I think it can be done even without pl, just two (using decode…) inserts statements with a proper select from the “source” table…

Comment: @ShinTakezou : Where did you read me saying I wish to use PL/SQL for this task?

Comment: @KaushikNayak **Nowhere**, I was just adding a comment on the oddness posed by this code — addressed to you just because you reminded the OP how powerful pl/sql is, so I followed the last statement adding that in this case I think he (the OP) even don't need that power.

Comment: @ShinTakezou  : Good that you mentioned... coz this line from OP "But I'm really disappointed with the way PL/SQL work"  - was really not amused by this.

Comment: @ShinTakezou Then can you explain the different behavior between the 2 codes? And you obviosuly, if I asked a question, it is not to get comment like "there is a better way" but rather getting to know this better way..  Thanks

Comment: You are right, Hey. Sorry. The fact is that right now I don't have an Oracle DB to do tests, and I usually do them before answering a solution or an explanation of a reason: I surely need to replicate it, or I can't see what's going on. For the alt solution, I was thinking something it should work with any db SQL-92 compliant, so I'm going to see what I can pull out from the hat as soon as I can  :-D

Comment: Guys you are not helping with your comments. I'm a Java dev not a PL/SQL dev and I'm struggling getting it right as no time to learn better PL/SQL. I would love knowing this query you have in mind or a better way to write the proc.I got many similar requirement, I would prefer use a proc to factorize each of these reqs in a clean way: A 'master' proc will later aggregate them. I'm using XE 11.2. Thanks

Comment: It's Sunday and you seem to be in a lot of hurry...!

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yep, the code freeze is tonight and we work 6am-9am Monday to Monday :) I'm just helping where I can whil I'm a Java dev.. ;)