# How to store SQL result in a variable and parse the result to identify a possible pattern?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g

The query below

```
INSERT INTO temp 
SELECT esd, 
       'E' 
FROM   test_data_sovlp 
WHERE  esd IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT td, 
       CASE is_db 
         WHEN 0 THEN 'S' 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'H' 
       END AS FLAG 
FROM   test_data_sovlp 
WHERE  td IS NOT NULL
```

return the following data:

```
|----------|----------|
|  DT      |  FLAG    |
|----------|----------|
|  10      |  E       |
|  20      |  H       |
|  30      |  E       |
|  40      |  E       |
|  50      |  E       |
|  60      |  S       |
|  70      |  H       |
|  75      |  E       |
|  80      |  H       |
|  100     |  H       |
|----------|----------|
```

when run against this table:

```
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    ID    |   ESD    |  TD      |   IS_DB  | TEST_SET |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    1     |  10      |  20      |    1     |    2     |
|    2     |  30      |  (null)  |    1     |    2     |
|    3     |  40      |  (null)  |    1     |    2     |
|    4     |  50      |  60      |    0     |    2     |
|    5     |  (null)  |  70      |    1     |    2     |
|    6     |  75      |  100     |    1     |    2     |
|    7     |  (null)  |  80      |    1     |    2     |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

***Note***: See the demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1415f/2) or my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432956/oracle-stored-procedure-and-cursor) for more details.

What I'm interested in is to concatenate the `FLAG` value return by the query above, in the `DT` order.

So for the query above, the concatenation (let's call it `q_result`) value is: `q_result = EHEEESEHH`.

I want then to parse then `q_result` by block of 2 characters to detect the possible presence of any of the following sequence:

```
HH      EE      HS      SE
```

During the parse, if a pattern match anywhere in `q_result`, the proc I would like to write must return `0`.
If no pattern match then the proc must return `1`.

**Question**

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do something like this:

```
select count(*)
from (select listagg(flag) within group (order by dt) as flags
      from temp
     ) x
where not regexp_like(flags, 'HH|EE|HS|SE');
```

Alternatively, you can use `lag()`:

```
select (case when count(*) = sum(case when flag2 not in ('HH', 'EE', 'HS', 'SE')
             then 1 else 0
        end) as return_value
from (select t.*,
             (lag(flag) over (order by dt) || flag) as flag2
      from temp
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks. That's sounds very much the answer. However got missing keyword `end) as return_value`.  A closing parenthesis before the `as` is missing but added it without success. Do you have an idea ? The first query seems to work if I remove the `not` (to return `1` in case of pattern mach). I will test it against others set of data. Thanks!