# Strange code behavior when runned in a stored procedure, but work fine when taken outside it

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

See demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee959/1/0)

The stored procedure returns:

```
|-------------|------------|
|   test_set  |  is_sovlp  |
|-------------|------------|
|   1         |  1         |
|   2         |  1         |
|-------------|------------|
```

While the expected result is:

```
|-------------|------------|
|   test_set  |  is_sovlp  |
|-------------|------------|
|   1         |  0         |
|   2         |  1         |
|-------------|------------|
```

What is surprising is that taken outside a stored procedure, the values returned are correct.

But in the stored procedure, they are not.

Do someone have any idea?

**Note**: more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433925/how-to-store-sql-result-in-a-variable-and-parse-the-result-to-identify-a-possibl)

Code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE IS_OVLP AS

is_sovlp VARCHAR2(1);
test_set NUMBER := 1;

BEGIN

    DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT('TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_OUTPUT_OVLP');

    --------------------------------------
    -- Populate TEMP_OUT_OVLP
    --------------------------------------

    INSERT INTO TEMP_OUTPUT_OVLP 
    SELECT ESD, 
           'E', 
           TEST_SET
    FROM   TEMP_INPUT_OVLP 
    WHERE  ESD IS NOT NULL 
    AND TEST_SET = test_set
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT TD, 
           CASE IS_DB 
             WHEN 0 THEN 'S' 
             WHEN 1 THEN 'H' 
           END AS FLAG,
           TEST_SET
    FROM   TEMP_INPUT_OVLP 
    WHERE  TD IS NOT NULL AND TEST_SET = test_set;

    -------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Lookup for pattern like HH|EE|HS|SE
    -- in aggregated result.
    -- Example: 
    -- EHESSHES   => 0
    -- EHEEESHEHH => 1
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    SELECT COUNT(*) into is_sovlp
    FROM (SELECT listagg(FLAG) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DT) as flags
          FROM TEMP_OUTPUT_OVLP
          WHERE TEST_SET = test_set
         ) x
    WHERE regexp_like(flags, 'HH|EE|HS|SE');

    dbms_output.put_line('Soft Overlap: ' || is_sovlp);

END IS_OVLP;
```

Input data:

```
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    ID    |   ESD    |  TD      |   IS_DB  | TEST_SET |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    1     |   10     |  20      |   1      |  1       |
|    2     |   30     |  (null)  |   0      |  1       |
|    3     |   (null) |  40      |   0      |  1       |
|    4     |   (null) |  50      |   0      |  1       |
|    5     |   (null) |  60      |   1      |  1       |
|    6     |   70     |  (null)  |   0      |  1       |
|    7     |   (null) |  100     |   0      |  1       |
|    8     |   10     |  20      |   1      |  2       |
|    9     |   30     |  (null)  |   0      |  2       |
|    10    |   40     |  (null)  |   0      |  2       |
|    11    |   50     |  60      |   0      |  2       |
|    12    |   (null) |  70      |   1      |  2       |
|    13    |   75     |  100     |   1      |  2       |
|    14    |   (null) |  80      |   1      |  2       |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

Comment: `TEST_SET = test_set` will be true for every row where `test_set` is not null. My guess would be that 'outside a stored proc' you used `TEST_SET = 1`.

Comment: That's correct and solved my problem ! So replaced the var declaration to `v_test_set NUMBER := 2;` instead of `test_set NUMBER := 2;`. I'm not strong in SQL, thought SQL will be able to differentiate both. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that every row in `TEMP_INPUT_OVLP` has a value for `TEST_SET`, and PL/SQL identifiers are case-insensitive, then the predicate

```
TEST_SET = test_set
```

will be true for every row. Probably when you tested the SQL on its own you used something like

```
TEST_SET = 1
```

Try changing it to:

```
TEST_SET = is_ovlp.test_set
```

or else rename the local variable. It is common practice to use a naming convention such as an `l_` prefix for local variables, e.g. `l_test_set`.