# LISTAGG equivalent for 10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g, string-aggregation

I'm on Oracle 10g and so unfortunately I can't use `listagg` (as this requires 11g).

So I would like to port the code below to an alternative for 10g:

```
select count(*) from (
    select listagg(flag) within group (order by dt) as flags
    from   temp_output_ovlp
)
where not regexp_like(flags, 'HH|EE|HS|SE');
```

This will search for matching `HH|EE|HS|SE` pattern within `EHEEESHEHH` when run against:

```
|----------|----------|
|  DT      |  FLAG    |
|----------|----------|
|  10      |  E       |
|  20      |  H       |
|  30      |  E       |
|  40      |  E       |
|  50      |  E       |
|  60      |  S       |
|  70      |  H       |
|  75      |  E       |
|  80      |  H       |
|  100     |  H       |
|----------|----------|
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1415f/2)

I tried `lag` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433925/how-to-store-sql-result-in-a-variable-and-parse-the-result-to-identify-a-possibl), available on 10g, but without success:

```
select (case when count(*) = sum(case when flag2 not in ('HH', 'EE', 'HS', 'SE')
             then 1 else 0
        end) as return_value
from (select t.*,
             (lag(flag) over (order by dt) || flag) as flag2
      from temp
     ) t;
```

**Questions**

1. Can someone tell me how I can make it work?
2. How does `COLLECT` (see [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306)) compare to `lag` in term of performance?

Thanks

EDIT:

**Expected results**

- `EHEEESHEHH` must return `1` as at least one of the following two letters patern (`HH|EE|HS|SE`) can be found (here `EE` and `HH`) in `EHEEESHEHH`.
- If the pattern were let say `EHESSSHEHE` then `0` must returned as none of the following two letters pattern (`HH|EE|HS|SE`) can be found in `EHESSSHEHE`.

**Note**: The pattern (eg `EHEEESHEHH`) if the result of the inner query `SELECT listagg(FLAG) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DT) as flags FROM TEMP_OUTPUT_OVLP` against the data table.

Comment: Please provide expected output by editing the question.

Comment: thanks, added the expected result

Comment: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The question is not duplicate with the link you provided. This one is to do without listagg (11g), the link is for using listagg. It use lag instead. Thx

Comment: See the section "10g and lower" in the accepted answer.

Comment: That's one possible answer indeed. But LAG, WM_CONCAT, XMLLAGG or COLLECT aren't there. As such, it isn't exhaustive or specific to the problem I want to solve.But I get your point and the reader can complete the duplicate you linked

Answer (score 2):

If it help anyone, got is work as follow:

```
    SELECT DECODE(return_value,0,0,1) result 
    FROM (SELECT 
            SUM(CASE WHEN (flag2 in ('HH', 'EE', 'HS', 'SE'))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                END) AS return_value
    FROM (SELECT
            (lag(flag) over (ORDER BY DT) || flag) AS flag2
              FROM TEMP_OUTPUT_OVLP)
    ) t;
```

It will return `1` for:

```
|----------|----------|
|  DT      |  FLAG    |
|----------|----------|
|  10      |  E       |
|  20      |  H       |
|  30      |  E       |
|  40      |  E       |
|  50      |  E       |
|  60      |  S       |
|  70      |  H       |
|  75      |  E       |
|  80      |  H       |
|  100     |  H       |
|----------|----------|
```

And `0` for :

```
|----------|----------|
|  DT      |  FLAG    |
|----------|----------|
|  10      |  E       |
|  20      |  H       |
|  30      |  E       |
|  40      |  H       |
|  50      |  E       |
|  60      |  S       |
|  70      |  H       |
|  75      |  E       |
|  80      |  H       |
|  100     |  E       |
|----------|----------|
```

as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Not that it matters much (as you've already found the solution), but - perhaps you'd be interested in two another options of aggregating values in 10g.

This one is *safe* to use:

```
SQL> select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, dname ||',') order by deptno).extract('//text()'), ',') depts
  2  from dept;

DEPTS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNTING,RESEARCH,SALES,OPERATIONS
```

WM_CONCAT is undocumented so you'd better not use it because Oracle might decide to remove it from future versions so ... bye-bye to backward compatibility.

```
SQL> select wm_concat(dname) depts
  2  from dept;

DEPTS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNTING,RESEARCH,SALES,OPERATIONS

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for these alternatives. Will have to check if one is faster than others.